# Self join on same table to return unique rows only

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| id  | name    | text              | fieldname |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 1   | item_1  | Title For Item 1  | title     |
| 2   | item_1  | Body For Item 1   | body      |
| 3   | item_2  | Title For Item 2  | title     |
| 4   | item_2  | Body For Item 2   | body      |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

It stores two parts of the same item in two different rows. They are related by the column `name`.

I need to retrieve the text from both rows for the same item, but on the same row. I want to end up with a result like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| name      | title             | text              |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| item_1    | Title For Item 1  | Body For Item 1   |
| item_2    | Title For Item 2  | Body For Item 2   |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm having a hard time understanding how to create a statement to accomplish this. Mysql isn't my forte. Every resource I've seen so far suggests this is as simple as just joining a table to itself on the matching column. However when I try it like that, I get duplicates of data, and not at all what I need:

```
SELECT
    t1.name as 'Name',
    t1.text as 'Title',
    t2.text as 'Body'
from test t2
inner join test t1
on t2.name = t1.name
```

The above outputs like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| name      | title             | text              |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| item_1    | Title For Item 1  | Title For Item 1  |
| item_1    | Title For Item 1  | Body For Item 1   |
| item_1    | Body For Item 1   | Title For Item 1  |
| item_1    | Body For Item 1   | Body For Item 1   |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A join isn't necessary. We could use conditions in expressions in the SELECT list, something like this:

```
SELECT t.name                                                        AS `Name`
     , MAX(CASE t.fieldname WHEN 'title'  THEN t.text ELSE NULL END) AS `Title`
     , MAX(CASE t.fieldname WHEN 'body'   THEN t.text ELSE NULL END) AS `Body`
  FROM test t
 GROUP
    BY t.name
```

Note that this will return one row for each "name" value, even if there are no rows that have "fieldname" values of 'title' and/or 'body'.

If we want to return only rows that have "fieldname" values of 'title' and 'body', we can add a WHERE clause

```
WHERE t.fieldname IN ('title','body')
```

if we want to ensure that we have both 'title' and 'body' (which is what the INNER JOIN would have done) we can do that in a HAVING clause

```
HAVING 2 = COUNT(DISTINCT IF(t.fieldname IN ('title','body'),t.fieldname,NULL))
```

---

But if there's some reason we have to use a JOIN operation, we could include conditions that restrict rows to "fieldname" values of 'title' and 'body'

```
SELECT t1.name  AS `Name`
     , t1.text  AS `Title`
     , t2.text  AS `Body`
  FROM test t1
  JOIN test t2
    ON t2.name = t1.name
   AND t2.fieldname = 'body'
 WHERE t1.fieldname = 'title'
```

If there's a chance that we have multiple rows with 'body' and 'title', and we want to return only a single row for a given "name", we can add a GROUP BY and aggregates in the SELECT list

```
SELECT t1.name       AS `Name`
     , MAX(t1.text)  AS `Title`
     , MAX(t2.text)  AS `Body`
  FROM test t1
  JOIN test t2
    ON t2.name = t1.name
   AND t2.fieldname = 'body'
 WHERE t1.fieldname = 'title'
 GROUP
    BY t1.name
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I needed. Very helpful explanation. I understand now what I was doing wrong with my query, and your explanation of alternatives has taught me some new things :)